# Understand how the compiler works

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, object-files

I'm studying the C++ programming language and I have a questions about the how the compiler create an executable file. My book says:

> C++ is a compiled language so you need to translate the source code in a file that the computer can execute. This file is generated by the compiler and it's called the object code ( .obj ), but a program like the hello world program is composed by a part that we written and part of the C++ library.

Which is this part in the hello world program?

Then my book says:

> You must compile and link the two parts of the program to produce an executable file.

Does this mean that the executable file is the result of linking the two parts of the program and that the object code can't be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two parts are 1) "your code that calls the print function and passes the string in", which is your compiled hello world program; 2) the code that *implements* the print function (say "std::cout <<"). We call it standard library.

Obviously, without the standard library object file, you can't get a complete executable because of lack of std::cout's implementation.

One of the reason that there *is* a standard library is to make the user code (your hello world file) more portable across different operating systems, because in Unix systems you actually have to use "write" function to print a string; but in other systems you may use functions other than "write". Standard library unifies it for you.

Details about standard library object file include techniques like template instantiation, which you may be not interested in for now.

Comment: so why my book before says : what you writw is called source code and what the program executes is called object code or executable.Object code file have the suffix .obj, than, my book says : we must link the two parts of a program to obtain an executable with suffix .exe. why ??

Comment: Why are they called source code/object code/executable? I didn't try to figure them out. Wiki pages may help you. Your book assumes a specific platform and even a specific IDE; those suffixes vary in other platforms

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ have to be compiled. You'll use a compiler that will translate your code into platform-specific executable.

Compiler does many steps:

- The code is first pre-processed (replacing macros (#define) by their value and include files (#include) by their content.
- Syntax analysis to check C++ syntax is valid
- Sematic analysis to construct a tree of instructions
- Optimization (if requested)
- Code generation: it writes assembly code specific to the target platform
- Linking: putting together all code into an executable program

At leats, that's what I remember from what I learn at school....

Answer (score 0):

That's right: C and C++ both have separate compilation and link steps.  The source is compiled to object code for that specific processor.  The object files and libraries are linked together and then executed.

Java and C# both use byte code that is interpreted and executed by their respective virtual machines.

Comment: Aren't Java and C# JIT compiled rather than interpreted?

Comment: @OMGtechy: That is an implementation detail. Certainly a Java card, for instance, doesn't attempt JIT compilation.

Comment: both are true.  you compile .java source to generate byte code in .class files.  the .class byte code is interpreted by the JVM.  yes, it uses statistics to optimize at runtime.

Comment: @duffymo: That's not JIT compilation, though. Most Java "interpreters" actually compile (some of) the bytecode into native machine language at runtime, for performance reasons. That is more than just "using statistics".

Comment: Agreed.  You'd almost wonder why they bother having us compile to .class files anymore.  Just read the .java file and cut out the middle man.