# Command Prompt Input and Output

Tags: c++, command-line-tool

I want to take data from 'input.txt' to run 'main.exe' and then save the result of that program with this data to 'output.txt'.
If possible, I would like to write wwith form  <input.txt> <output.txt>.
[image]

Comment: Your output shows that you are trying to run your code. You can't run a cpp file or a header. You need to compile these first into an executable and run the executable.  I am sure there is a duplicate that explains what a compiler is and what it does.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826277/understand-how-the-compiler-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826277/understand-how-the-compiler-works)

Comment: The Visual Studio command prompt does not run source code. It's a normal windows command prompt (cmd.exe) with environment variables and paths setup for your compiler so that you could build your program directly in the command prompt using your compiler which is `cl.exe`. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to compile your c++ program, then run it with the two parameters. See [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) for some tutorials on file in and file out and the resource for taking in command line arguments: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/